# EE 2.5.5 not searching in custom wygwam field

Tags: wygwam, search

I have a site that's using a custom wygwam field for the body of an article page. I've set the field up to be searchable, however, EE is only showing results that have the keyword(s) in the title. Is it not possible to search a wygwam field or is this a known bug?

Comment: Can you share your Search Form template tag?